# Удаление объекта из БД

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть 3 класса:

```
@Entity
public class А {
    ...  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "а", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
     orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<В> bObj = new HashSet<B>();
    ...  
}  

@Entity
public class B {

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Integer amount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", nullable = false)
    private C c;
}  

@Entity
public class C {
    ...  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "c", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<В> bObj = new HashSet<B>();  
    ...  
}
```

Я не понимаю, как настроить связь `@OneToMany`, что бы при удалении объекта класса А удалялись все связанные с ним объекты класса В?
Что-то я запутался...
Кидает ошибки:

```
[ERROR] (DAO-слой класса А.java:33) - Ошибка при удалении. id = 5
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

и

```
        Caused by:  
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:  
        Cannot delete or update a parent row:  
        a foreign key constraint fails (`таблица В`, CONSTRAINT  
    `FK_bbpbxkkfko0nwn5uleye8org4` FOREIGN KEY (`а_id`) REFERENCES `таблица С)
```

Часть кода убрана, названия поменял для простоты.
З.Ы. Как вариант удалять объекты класса В по списку который мы получаем от А, и потом удалять А... но может есть решение проще с правильной настройкой?

Ага, понятно. Тогда вопрос в другом, почему hibernate не создает(и не обновляет) схему с `ON DELETE CASCADE` если я для него всё сделал:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "а_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)<---
    private А а;
```

Руками я поправлю, но всё же...